# How to make browser fixed when executing my jquery code

Tags: jquery, html, css

One of my projects web page is too lengthy. So I decided to add a small piece of jQuery code to a button which says:

```
 <a class="button" align="center" href="#"><div id="clickMe">Show me!.</div>
```

When a user presses this button the web page will be fully displayed. Here is the jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clickMe").click(function(){
        $("img").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#picFrame").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

I am hiding the display part of the page using this code

```
<div id="picFrame">
Bla bla goes here
</div>
```

When the user presses the show more button the content will be displayed.

But the problem is that this content is displayed at the bottom of the page. And when the user hits this button the browser will automatically scroll up to the header again. The user has to scroll down to see the contents. I want to avoid this.

After user submission the browser needs to be fixed at the same position where the browser was previously. The jQuery should execute and the contents should be shown. Any ideas?.

Comment: You can Use focus();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**jQuery JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ucs1rfa/)

It's because you have `href='#'` which sends it to the top of the page.

You can either do `href=''` so it doesn't go anywhere, or in your jQuery, have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clickMe").click(function(e){
        $("img").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#picFrame").slideToggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

`e.preventDefault();` will stop it from jumping to the top of the page. Make sure to include the `e` in the click function too.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use an empty href attribute as suggested by others, it could break the documents validity.
From the **RFC 2396, URI Generic Syntax** Section:

4.2. Same-document References

A URI reference that does not contain a URI is a reference to the
   current document. In other words, an empty URI reference within a
   document is interpreted as a reference to the start of that document,
   and a reference containing only a fragment identifier is a reference
   to the identified fragment of that document [...]

Expand your JS instead like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clickMe").click(function(evt){ //Add event object to the callback function
        evt.stopPropagation(); //Prevents event propagation/bubbling
        evt.preventDefault(); //Prevents browser's default behaviour when clicking
        $("img").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#picFrame").slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: `return false` from a click event does both `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()`. You do not need all three :)

Comment: True, somehow this slipped my attention. Indeed `return false` should trigger the desired behaviour already.